# Is Taittireya Samhita of Yajurveda is a different book or a chapter of Yajurveda?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda, krishna-yajurveda

Like Sri Valmiki Ramayana consists of chapters like bala kanda,sundar kanda etc,so the Taittireya Samhita is a chapter of Yajurveda or a different book?

Comment: You may check [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18749/why-is-yajurveda-classified-as-krishna-and-shukla/).

Comment: Balakanda, Sundara Kanda are not chapters. They are the divisions. These Kandas have chapters in them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taittariya samhita = Valmiki ramayana

Baala etc kaandas = 8 chapters of kaandas of TS

So TS is not a chapter of Yajurveda but **TS itself is Yajurveda.**

It is known as krishna yajurveda and it has samhita and brahmana portion in a mixed form.

> The Taittiriya Samhita— (TS) which consists of 8 books or kaandas,
>   subdivided in chapters or prapathakas, further subdivided into
>   individual hymns. Some individual hymns in this Samhita have gained
>   particular importance in Hinduism; e.g. TS 4.5 and TS 4.7 constitute
>   the Shri Rudram Chamakam, while 1.8.6.i is the Shaivaite Tryambakam
>   mantra.
>
> The Taittiriya Brahmana (having three kaandas). Part of kathaka shakha
>   brahmana is also included in this shakha.
>
> the Taittiriya Aranyaka (having seven prashnas)

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taittiriya_Shakha)

You can also check this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18989/what-are-the-vedas-technically-how-can-upanishads-be-called-vedas-when-some-par) to know more on the Vedas .

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda If you are satisfied with the answer, accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the answer.  Saying thanks is a chatty comment.