# Why are parts of Rig Veda repeated in the other Vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rig-veda

If other Vedas have repeated and expounded upon Rig Veda, why read all four Vedas? Isn't Rig Veda enough?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/similarities-and-differences-in-the-four-vedas/

Comment: you have multiple questions. the last two are asking for an opinion, which makes the whole question subject to be closed. edit your question.

Comment: I don't understand how it is opinion. Please help me make this question better

Comment: Yes, "Some of the mantras are found in two or three Vedas uniformly. The reason for this is that the division of Veda is done according to usefulness of mantra for Rutvij for Yajnanushthan. Thus the presence of same mantra in other Veda in different occasion for the different class of Rutvij is natural, even though the same mantra is found in other Veda in another occasion for another Rutvij." - from the Q/A @LakshmiNarayanan linked.

Comment: @RubelliteFae if you've self close-voted, you can click on button something like "yes, that solved my problem" so-that post will be closed by system.

Comment: @Pandya Thank you. I am new to the moderation tools. At first I thought to delete it. But then I thought about how I couldn't find the question I duplicated. So, I thought maybe closing was better so other people could find the original question easier.

Comment: @RubelliteFae No problem. Yes, closing is better as visitors can easily find by searching on the site.