# Is Baskala Shaka of Rig veda Authentic?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rig-veda, translation-request

Vedas are the primary and oldest scriptures of Hinduism. Many sages wrote them and they are pure authentic and most sacred scriptures of Hinduism. Entire Hindu philosphy is based on them. The four Vedas are Rig Veda, Sama Veda, Yajur Veda and Atharva Veda.

According to some sources there were thousand branches of it but now only 10-12 branches are left. So my question is that **is the Baskala Shaka of Rig veda as authentic as other Shakas? And can it be regarded as Sacred as other Shakas**? Baskala Shaka  also  contains Shiv Sankalp Sukta and Lakshmi Sukta.

Comment: Hundred percent authentic. All shakhas existing today are genuine. You should try to learn some of it from a pathshala whenever you have free.time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Bāṣkala was one of the disciplines of Paila who has received Rigveda Samhita from VedaVyasa. As graphically represented in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31727/277):

> [image]

[Refer 54<sup>th</sup> verse of Srimad Bhagvata Canto 4, Chapter 6](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31727/277) where Bashkala is clearly mentioned as one direct discipline of Paila.

> पैलः स्वसंहितामूचे इन्द्रप्रमितये मुनिः
>   **बाष्कलाय** च सोऽप्याह शिष्येभ्यः संहितां स्वकाम् ॥ १२.६.५४ ॥
>
> pailaḥ sva-saṁhitām ūce
>   indrapramitaye
>   **bāṣkalāya** ca so ’py āha
>   śiṣyebhyaḥ saṁhitāṁ svakām
>
> After dividing his saṁhitā into two parts, the wise Paila spoke it to Indrapramiti and **Bāṣkala.**

Charanavyuha Sutras of [Shaunaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaunaka) mentions five Shakas of Rigveda:

Rigveda Khanda:

> एतेषां शाखाः पञ्च विधा भवन्ति ॥ ७ ॥
>   आश्वलायनी, शङ्खायनी, शाकला, **बाष्कला**, मापडूकायनश्चेति ॥ ८ ॥

So, Bāṣkala is authentic Shakha of Rigveda.

Comment: Good answer. Do you have or can you provide English translation of Baskala shakha?@Pandya

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda Thanks; if you're satisfied with the answer you can [accept it](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). For getting Bashkala Samhita of Rigveda, it would be good to ask a [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about it.

Comment: Wonderful !!! Thank you.