# Which are seven Hotā mentioned in Śiva Saṅkalpa Sūkta?

Tags: yajna, priests

Śiva Saṅkalpa Sūkta is a sūkta of six Śloka from 34<sup>th</sup> chapter of Ṣukla Yajurveda. This hymn is dedicated to (a prayer) for having mind of Śiva (auspicious, good) Saṅkalpa (thoughts, intentions).

Fourth mantra read as follows:

> येनेदं भूतं भुवनं भविष्यत् परिगृहिततममृतेन सर्वम् ।
>   येन यज्ञस्तायते **सप्त होता** तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।।
>
> yenedaṃ bhūtaṃ bhuvanaṃ bhaviṣyat parigṛhitatamamṛtena sarvam |
>   yena yajñastāyate **sapta hotā** tanme manaḥ śivasaṃkalpamastu ||

[English translation](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk34.htm):

> 4 Whereby, immortal, all is comprehended, the world which is,
>   and what shall be hereafter,
>   Whereby spreads sacrifice with **seven Hotars**, may that, my
>   mind, be moved by right intention.

As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16121/277) there are mainly four types of group of ṛtvij (Vedic Priests) who accomplish the whole Yajna, Hotṛ, Udgātṛ, Adhvaryu and Brahma which recites hymns from Ṛg, Sāma, Yajur and Atharva  Vedas respectively.

Here seven Hotā are mentioned. I want to know which those seven Hotās are.

Answer (score 4):

The sapta hotas are body, organs of actions, organs of perceptions, mind, intelligence, soul and supreme-soul.

Quoting it from : [Yajurveda 34/4](http://www.neelkanthdhaam.org/Yved-3.html)

> (87) YENEDAM BHUTAM BHUVANAM BHAVISHYAT PARIGRIHITA MRITEN SARVAM|
>   YENA YAGYASTAAYATE SAPTA HOTAA TANME MANAH SHIVA SANKALPAM ASTU (34/4, Yajurveda)
>
> May my non-perishable mind, which has imbibed all the knowledge from the past, present and future and which helps in the accomplishment of Yagya performed by 'Sapta hotaganas’ be of good resolution.
>   Our life is like a 'Yagya', **which is accomplished by the means of 'Sapta hotas'-body, organs of actions, organs of perceptions, mind, intelligence, soul and supreme-soul.** The mind can be compared to a very fast galloping horse, which is very difficult to control. If it is pure then virtuous deeds are ensured. On the contrary, if the mind is pervaded by impure thoughts, then success always remains elusive. Therefore to attain success, a pure mind is an absolute necessity.

Comment: in any typical yagyas there is always 16 priest out which 7 hotr are rjtvik who recite righveda.. udgatrs are yajur vedis who perform yagnya they are 4 rest or sama vedic preist and athar veda preist

Comment: @PrasannaR What you're saying may be Yajnik interpretation which is most authentic interpretation, in my answer it is Adhyatmika interpretation.

Comment: got it sir.. decipher yajur in adyatmic way is challenge.. kudos to you

Comment: @PrasannaR Thanks! You may want to add an answer with Yajnik interpretation if you have it with a valid reference. BTW In the commentary of ESSENCE OF ASHTAADASHA UPANISHADS  by VDN Rao, he interprets it as seven rays of the Sun.

Comment: Whose commentary/translation is this?

Answer (score 1):

```
येनेदं भूतं भुवनं भविष्यत् परिगृहिततममृतेन सर्वम् ।
येन यज्ञस्तायते सप्तहोता तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।।
```

Seven entities are the one which helps and involved in knowing supreme GOD or spreading his actions with gratitude. There are multiple commentaries available of the Mantra.

The one which I like it -- Seven subtle entities involve in the one most subtle (Buddhi/Mahattatva)particle through which soul is binded by supreme eternally.

I can show - what I meant to say is .

Here , **Sapthota are (5 subtle sense partcles (Gyanendriya)) + 1 Man + 1 Ahankaar** They all contribute in knowing the world's/nature's past , Present and Even Future(through Past analysed information). We call it as **Uha** in sanskrit.

Here , Using Subtle partcle (**Buddhi**) one can know all information regarding time and space . You can transcend time and space(**भुवनं**) according to your capacity.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to HSE! In the meanwhile you can browse through [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). It’s a nice informative post for reference.